# ZF2 resolver could not resolve to a file (but works on development environment)

Tags: zend-framework2

I've gone through the other similar questions on here and have tried numerous things though to no avail.

I have a dashboard controller that works correctly on my development machine, though when it is uploaded to the production server it reports:

> Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "Dashboard\Dashboard\Index"; resolver could not resolve to a file

I've checked my `module.config.php` file for the view-template (and it's correctly listed on there)

```
'template_path_stack' => array(
    'dashboard' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
),
```

And the file is also at that physical location...

I'm not sure what I am missing in terms of this, so any pointers would be great.

UPDATE:

Here is the code for the controller:

```
public function indexAction() {
        //check the users authenticity
        $userId = null;
        $auth = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('zfcuser_auth_service');

        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            $user = $auth->getIdentity();
            $userId = $user->getId();
        } else {
            $this->redirect()->toUrl('/user/login');
        }

        //set the view model to improve performance
        //http://samminds.com/2012/11/zf2-performance-quicktipp-1-viewmodels/
        $viewModel = new ViewModel();
        $viewModel->setTemplate('Dashboard\Dashboard\Index');

        //return the amount of counts the various items have outstanding       
        $dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        $systemRepo = $this->getSystemRepo($dbAdapter);

        $internalContacts = $systemRepo->widgetAlphabetList("Internal Contacts", $systemRepo->getInternalContacts(), 'firstname', 'surname');

       return $viewModel->setVariables(array(
                    'internalContacts' => $internalContacts
        ));
    }
```

And the full path to the file is (add index.phtml on the end of the below):

/var/www/html/module/Dashboard/view/dashboard/dashboard

Comment: Try replacing `__DIR__ . '/../view'` with `dirname(__DIR__) . '/view'`

Comment: Please show the code in your controller (where you set the view).

Comment: What is the full path to the file?

Comment: Cheers guys, have updated my post to reflect my answers to the above questions. Dave, cheers, I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using forward slashes `/` instead of back slashes `\ ` when you set the view template?

Comment: Have a look at case sensitivity of your file, directories and configs. This is a common issue when developing in other OS (i.e. Windows filesystem is case insensitive and linux case sensitive)

Comment: Cheers Crisp, this has worked for me. Cheers to the rest of you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess dev machine is not a case sensitive file system and prod is case sensitive. Try this:

```
$viewModel->setTemplate('dashboard/dashboard/index')
```

Comment: Hello, I tried that but it didn't work either, though it does look better aesthetically so I changed them all  my template calls to be lower case (just in case)